# webrtc onaddstream not called second peer for one to many video chat

Tags: webrtc

I am facing problem in one to many video chat calling however one to one is working perfectly. the issue is that when owner create the connection with first one peer it work fine however owner call to second-one peer first one remote stream freeze and owner not getting remote stream from second-one user i found that onaddstream method not called for second one user.

Comment: glad you are able to explain your problem. It could be a number of things...the only way to give a specific answer to help would be for you to post the relevant source code.

Comment: You need to put checks inside onaddstream method for peer one's stream and for peer two's stream. check again onaddstream function must be called if you have defined a function for this using : 'pc.onaddstream = handleRemoteStreamAdded;'

Comment: will owner have to create one more peer coonection  object if he has to do video chat with other two user parallel ?

Comment: can he use same object to connecting with other one user